# How can another process call $signal()$ when one process is executing $wait()$ in its busy waiting loop?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency

A semaphore is a variable that, apart from initialization is accessed through only two standard atomic operations wait(s) and signal(s).

```
wait(S){
    while S <= 0
    ; //no-op
    s--;
}

signal(S){
    s++;
}
```

The function $wait()$ is an atomic operation which means that either it is executed in its entirety or it is not executed. Let us suppose that we call $wait(a)$ upon a semaphore variable $a$. And let us assume the initial value is $0$. This means the criterion for the while loop is satisfied and it goes into a while loop. It can only come out of the while loop if the value of the semaphore $a$ is $\gt$ 0. This can occur, if some process sets the value of $a$ to $1$ by calling $signal(a)$. But since $wait()$ and $signal()$ are atomic operations and since we have already entered into the busy waiting while loop in $wait()$ when the value of $a$ was $0$, isn't this loop supposed to run indefinitely since its atomic? How can another process call $signal()$ when one process is executing $wait()$ in its busy waiting loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion that `wait()` and `signal()` are atomic is incorrect. The increment/decrement to `s` within the functions (`s++`, `s--`), are what's atomic.

That being said, what you have given here is only one possible *implementation* of a semaphore. An OS may or may not implement semaphores in this way, and they probably will choose a more efficient implementation. What's more important is to grasp the semantics of a semaphore, which you seem to understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Semaphore do not work the way you have described. They are more like shared variables. So even inside the loop S can get modifies and the first process will come out of the loop. Note it is not same as while(1){}; .

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `wait()` as given by you is very simplest. The checking of value of `S` (`S<=0`) and its possible modification (`S--`) must be performed without interruption. If you write `wait()` function as you have written here then, when a process has found that `S>0` and it is going to modify `S` (`S--`) then it can stop between checking value of `S` (`S<=0`) and its possible modification (`S--`). If this happens mutual exclusion will not be satisfied. Also, if a process finds that `S<=0`, it has to simply busy wait and other process should be allowed to enter `signal()` and increment `S`. You will need to add few lines in your code to handle such situations.